# How can I make the textbox say the URL of the webpage that the web browser is currently on?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I want the `TextBox` to show the URL of the web page that the web browser is currently on. The code shown below doesn't seem to solve my problem.

The `TextBox` doesn't change when I navigate to the previous page by calling `WebBrowser1.GoBack()`

Help is sincerely appreciated!

I've tried this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
  TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Url.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the [`WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted) instead. It is fired whenever a page has finished loading. There's also the [`WebBrowser.Nagivated` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated), which is fired whenever it has successfully connected to a site (but not yet finished loading the entire page - the URL is still accessible, though).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Vincent's and ajakblackgoat's answers are correct. The reason you're not seeing the URL change in the answer you accepted is because the `GoBack` method runs asynchronously (on a different thread). The code in the `Button1.Click` event handler falls through to your `TextBox1.Text` line before the `WebBrowser` control can change its URL. You might consider changing your accepted answer or asking preciousbetine to edit his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Navigated event of the WebBrowser to get it's current URL.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.GoBack()
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigated(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigated
    TextBox1.Text = e.Url.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Christoffer, Vision Vincent and InteXX.